# mockkObject calling real method instead of mocked object class | Android | Kotlin | Unit test

Tags: java, android, kotlin, unit-testing, mockk

I am using mockk for unit testing my Android project.
I am having an object class and that object class is used inside the repository which I am testing.
The mockk library I am using : "io.mockk:mockk-android:1.13.7"

Repository :

```
class BusinessRepository() {

    companion object {
        private var businessRepository:BusinessRepository? = null
        val instance: BusinessRepository?
            get() {
                if (businessRepository == null) {
                    businessRepository = BusinessRepository()
                }
                return businessRepository
            }
    }

    suspend fun fetchBusinessData(context:Context,businessData:MutableLiveData<Feature>?, ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO) = withContext(ioDispatcher) 
    {
        val feature = ObjBeingMocked.getFeatures(context)
        businessData?.postValue(feature)
        return@withContext
    }
}
```

Test Code :

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class BusinessRepositoryTest {
    lateinit var businessRepository: BusinessRepository
    var businessDataObservable: MutableLiveData<Feature> = MutableLiveData()

    lateinit var instrumentationContext: Context
    lateinit var testDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
    private val mainThreadSurrogate = Executors
        .newSingleThreadExecutor { Thread(it, "UI-thread") }
        .asCoroutineDispatcher()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate)
        testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

        businessRepository = BusinessRepository.instance!!
        instrumentationContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
    }

    @Test
    fun `fetchBusinessDataTest`() = runBlocking {

        mockkObject(ObjBeingMocked) {
            val featureMock = mockk<Feature>()

            every {
                ObjBeingMocked.getFeatures(instrumentationContext)
            } returns featureMock

            businessRepository.fetchBusinessDataExtra(
                instrumentationContext,
                businessDataObservable,
                testDispatcher
            )

            delay(500)

            val responseValue = businessDataObservable.value
            assert(responseValue != null)
        }

    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        unmockkAll()
    }
}
```

ObjBeingMocked.getFeatures :

```
object ObjBeingMocked {
         fun getFeatures(context: Context): Feature {
            val featureJson = JSONObject(getFeaturesString(context)!!)
            val features = Feature(featureJson)
            return features
        }

        fun getSharedPref(context: Context): String? {
            // for testing the scenario I am returning null here
            return null
        }
}
```

Now when I run the test it is throwing the null pointer exception which is happening inside the `ObjBeingMocked.getFeatures` -> `JSONObject(getFeaturesString(context)!!)` -> `getFeaturesString(context)` returns null in real method.

But it should not happens if ObjBeingMocked being mocked.

I have tried Matt's blog on this https://matthew-b-groves.medium.com/matts-tidbits-29-how-to-mock-kotlin-singletons-without-using-powermock-938da069fa88

Making ObjBeingMocked to implement a interface `IObjBeingMocked`.
Mock that interface and injecting the mocked into `fetchBusinessData` method.

Now everything working fine. But ObjBeingMocked is being used at so many places in the project.
Injecting IObjBeingMocked to all methods inside all repositories was a heavy task.

Also not sure why `ObjBeingMocked.getFeatures(instrumentationContext)` is calling real method eventhough stub method is there in the test.

```
mockkObject(ObjBeingMocked) {
            val featureMock = mockk<Feature>()

            every {
                ObjBeingMocked.getFeatures(instrumentationContext)
            } returns featureMock
```

Comment: Kotlin methods and classes (and objects) are `final` by default. Most mocking can't deal with that. You'll need something like `kotlin-allopen`.

Comment: In the `BusinessRepository` and your test class, it looks like `ObjBeingMocked.getFeatures` is called with only one argument (context), but in the definition of `ObjBeingMocked`, the function `getFeatures` takes 3 arguments (a, b, context). Can you please adapt your question to be consistent?

Comment: Did you try to mock `ObjBeingMocked.getFeatures(any())` instead of `ObjBeingMocked.getFeatures(instrumentationContext)`?